# Long Press not working properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I am faceing a small prob. Please help me.

When i press and hold on my view my function called 2-3 times and some times after releasing hold the long press function again called.

In View did load

```
-(void)viewdidload
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture =
        [[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)] autorelease];

        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
        [self.view release];
}
    -(void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender 
    {
        NSLog(@"******Long Press*******");

}
```

***Long press printed*** many times.

Comment: why are you releasing the view of the view controller?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to just return from longPress if the gesture has not ended. Put this code right at the top of longPress:

```
if (sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    return;
}
```